# Error get current route name same path in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I define route name in route.js

```
...

    const routes = [
        {
            path: "/region-price/:state_id?",
            component: RegionPrice,
            name: "region-price"
        },
        {
            path: "/region-price/city_info",
            component: RegionPrice,
            name: "region-price-city"
        },
        {
            path: "/region-price/area_info",
            component: RegionPrice,
            name: "region-price-area"
        }
    ];

...
```

And .vue file

```
...
computed: {
   currentRouteName() {
      return this.$route.name;
   }
},
created() {
   console.log(this.currentRouteName);
},
...
```

This is my result

https://test.com/region-price/1 -> route name is `region-price` ok

https://test.com/region-price/city_info -> route name `region-price-city`, but result is `region-price`

https://test.com/region-price/city_info?city_id=1 -> route name `region-price-city`, but result is `region-price`

https://test.com/region-price/area_info -> route name is `region-price-area`, but result is `region-price`, too

Answer (score 1):

All these routes use the same component and you're only console logging at component's creation, which only happens one time for as long as you're routing to the same component.  That's part of the magic of a framework like Vue, it doesn't recreate the whole DOM every time something changes, it only updates what's necessary.  A better idea would be to display `currentRouteName` in your template somewhere. You should see it updating to the correct value.